# Magento 2 : extensionpool, read handlers and save handlers

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, entity-manager

Can anyone explain to me how to use ReadHandler, SaveHandler and the use of the EntityManager/ExtensionPool?

I'm trying to wrap my head around it, but I can't quite understand how to implement it. If I understand correctly, these can be used to perform additional persistent operations on objects, like creating many-to-many relations, like they are used in the CMS module to link the entity to the store.

I'm trying to do the same thing by relating another entity to CMS pages, but I can't seem to get it working. That is, if I'm using this design pattern properly.

Can anyone share some light on this?
I'm sorry I can't share some code at this moment, since I'm not at my work.

**EDIT:** This is the code I'm currently using:

I've added `cms_page_form.xml` to my modules' `view/adminhtml/ui_component`-folder, so I have an extra tab that displays the customer groups:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer_groups">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Groups</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="customer_groups">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Model\Config\Source\Group\Multiselect</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Groups</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customer_group</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This works; the tab is rendered and the customer groups are displayed. None are selected by default.

This is my entry in my global `di.xml` to register my save- and read-handlers. My inspiration was looking at how stores are saved on CMS pages:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="extensionActions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="read" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="customerGroupReader"
                          xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Relation\CustomerGroup\ReadHandler</item>
                </item>
                <item name="create" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="customerGroupCreator"
                          xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Relation\CustomerGroup\SaveHandler</item>
                </item>
                <item name="update" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="customerGroupUpdater"
                          xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Relation\CustomerGroup\SaveHandler</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

This is my save handler:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Relation\CustomerGroup;

use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page as PageResource;

/**
 * Class SaveHandler
 */
class SaveHandler implements ExtensionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var PageResource
     */
    protected $pageResource;

    /**
     * SaveHandler constructor.
     * @param PageResource $pageResource
     */
    public function __construct(
        PageResource $pageResource
    )
    {
        $this->pageResource = $pageResource;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $entity
     * @param array $arguments
     */
    public function execute($entity, $arguments = [])
    {
        $connection = $this->pageResource->getConnection();

        // First delete all existing relations:
        $connection->delete('cms_page_customer_group', sprintf('page_id = %d', (int) $entity->getId()));

        // Re-create the relations:
        foreach ($entity->getData('customer_group') as $customerGroupId) {
            $connection->insert('cms_page_customer_group', [
                'page_id' => (int) $entity->getId(),
                'customer_group_id' => (int) $customerGroupId
            ]);
        }

        return $entity;
    }
}
```

Up to this point everything works. If I select customer groups in the admin, the save handler gets executed and the proper rows are added to the database.

This is my read handler:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Relation\CustomerGroup;

use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page as PageResource;

/**
 * Class ReadHandler
 */
class ReadHandler implements ExtensionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var PageResource
     */
    protected $pageResource;

    /**
     * SaveHandler constructor.
     * @param PageResource $pageResource
     */
    public function __construct(
        PageResource $pageResource
    ) {
        $this->pageResource = $pageResource;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $entity
     * @param array $arguments
     */
    public function execute($entity, $arguments = [])
    {
        if ($entity->getId()) {
            $connection = $this->pageResource->getConnection();

            $customerGroupIds = $connection
                ->fetchCol(
                    $connection
                        ->select()
                        ->from('cms_page_customer_group', ['customer_group_id'])
                        ->where('page_id = ?', (int)$entity->getId())
                );

            $entity->setData('customer_group', $customerGroupIds);
        }

        return $entity;
    }
}
```

This is where I'm stuck. The handler works and gets executed. If I perform a `var_dump()` on `$customerGroupIds` they are populated with the correct results from the database.

However, in the adminhtml, none of the customer groups in the multiselect are selected. I think I'm really close into solving this one, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. My guts tell me it might have something to do with how I declared the multiselect in `cms_page_form.xml`, but I'm not sure what it is.

By the way, this is an example of the database scheme:

```
|page_id|customer_group_id|
|-------|-----------------|
|29     |1                |
|29     |2                |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am using the save approach, like you I used the reference from CMS Page module. But SaveHandler and ReadHandler both are not working in my case. Do you have any idea about that.

Comment: My `save handler` is not getting called. Read Handler is getting called. Following the same approach. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer on my own question (although I'm not sure if it's **the** answer):

The Read Handler works as expected and makes sure that the data is added to my model if I load it (for example) using a repository.

So that just left me with the admingrid. After looking through the original `cms_page_form.xml` I noticed that the data of the form was populated by using `Magento\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider`. When I looked at this class I noticed a method called `getData()` that uses the **collection** to fetch the entities, not the repository. Probably because the data provider is a general concept that can also be used in grids and stuff (please correct me if I'm wrong).

And the collection did not take the `ReadHandler` into account. I looked at the collection and the `getItems()`-method and stuff, but I couldn't find a proper way to add my custom attribute.

So I ended up with writing a plugin for `Magento\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider::getData`.

`di.xml`:

```
<!--
    Plugin to add customer_group to dataprovider:
-->
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider">
    <plugin name="private_pages_cms_dataprovider"
            type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider"/>
</type>
```

And my plugin code:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider $subject
 * @param array $result
 * @return array
 */
public function afterGetData(\Magento\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider $subject, array $result)
{
    foreach ($result as $pageId => &$data) {
        $data['customer_group'] = ...
    }
    return $result;
}
```

So this works now, but I'm not sure if this is the proper - Magento - way on how to deal with this. Can anyone share some thoughts on this?

Comment: I think you are missing HydratorPool :)

Comment: @KeyurShah I have got `hydratorPool` as well as `attributePool`, read handler is getting called but not save handler. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In your ResourceModel\Page, you should add function save enitityManager;
the issue worked with follow code:

```
namespace <your namespace>
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\EntityManager;

     ...

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $entityManager;


public function __construct(
        ...
        EntityManager $entityManager
    )
    {
        ...
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        ...
    }
...
...

 /**
     * @param AbstractModel $object
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function save(AbstractModel $object)
    {
        $this->entityManager->save($object);
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign Handlers in your di.xml If you look at cms page and cms blocks this part is clear. I'll explain using CMS but for your module it could be different.

```
    <type name="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="extensionActions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="read" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storeReader" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Relation\Store\ReadHandler</item>
                </item>
                <item name="create" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storeCreator" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Relation\Store\SaveHandler</item>
                </item>
                <item name="update" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storeUpdater" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Relation\Store\SaveHandler</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="read" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storeReader" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\Relation\Store\ReadHandler</item>
                </item>
                <item name="create" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storeCreator" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\Relation\Store\SaveHandler</item>
                </item>
                <item name="update" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storeUpdater" xsi:type="string">Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\Relation\Store\SaveHandler</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

You also need your Meta Data pool setup in your di.xml. Which is the connection to your linked fields

```
    <type name="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="metadata" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="entityTableName" xsi:type="string">cms_page</item>
                <item name="identifierField" xsi:type="string">page_id</item>
            </item>
            <item name="Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="entityTableName" xsi:type="string">cms_block</item>
                <item name="identifierField" xsi:type="string">block_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Since readHandler is straight forward. For **SaveHandler Note the newStores in CMS page hander**

```
    $oldStores = $this->resourceCampaign->lookupStoreIds((int)$entity->getId());
    $newStores = (array)$entity->getStores();
```

This is important If you pass StoreId as your list of stores from edit multiselect field This field need to change to **getStoreId()**

New Modification should be

```
$newStores = (array)$entity->getStoreId();
```

If somehow if you decide to use Stores to store New stores then leave it as it is