# Magento2.3.5 New Column to cms page store with declarative Schemas no saving

Tags: magento2.3.5, custom-field, declarative-schema, savedata

I have added a new column with declarative schema found here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html

Is all added to the table `cms_page_store` and the backend form but when I save I can see the data in post but is not populating the field in `cms_page_store` table.

My setup:

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="cms_page_store">
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="ucri" nullable="true" length="50" comment="Unique Code Cmc Page Relation Identifier"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="unique" referenceId="CMS_PAGE_STORE_UCRI_STORE_ID">
            <column name="ucri"/>
            <column name="store_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

**cms_page_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="search_engine_optimisation">
        <field name="ucri" sortOrder="1">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Unique Code</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">ucri</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**db_shcema_whitelist.json**

```
{
    "cms_page_store": {
        "column": {
            "ucri": true
        },
        "constraint": {
            "CMS_PAGE_STORE_UCRI_STORE_ID": true
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea ami missing something else here ?

Comment: is there any specific requirement of storing data in "cms_page_store" table? you can create custom column in "cms_page" table and data will be automatically stored in table and populated in backend using this approach.

Comment: @RahulBarot Yes, I guess that would be the solution which I've already tried and work. But I have a problem with that as I need this custom field to be unique with store_id field. adding it to `cms_page_store` I have added unique key between them, But how can I do that adding to `cms_page` table?  When I run `setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist` gives error `Table cms_page do not have column with name store_id`.

Comment: Yes, it will show error because "cms_page" table does not contain the store_id column, on page save it checks for any new store is added to page then it will create entry to "cms_page_store" with page row_id and store_id.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that's not possible as the Docs says: The primary and unique constraints are called “internal” constraints, because **they can be applied only to the scope of the table where they are created.** Internal constraints define one or more column subnodes. Each subnode defines a constrained column

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the logic to bind two fields as unique, below class is used to store data in the **cms_page_store** table.

You can override it using preference or you can add your custom logic in plugin and store custom column data.

> Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\Relation\Store\SaveHandler

In the execute function you can find code for delete and insert record as below

For delete

```
$delete = array_diff($oldStores, $newStores);
if ($delete) {
    $where = [
        $linkField . ' = ?' => (int)$entity->getData($linkField),
        'store_id IN (?)' => $delete,
    ];
    $connection->delete($table, $where);
}
```

For insert

```
$insert = array_diff($newStores, $oldStores);
if ($insert) {
    $data = [];
    foreach ($insert as $storeId) {
        $data[] = [
            $linkField => (int)$entity->getData($linkField),
            'store_id' => (int)$storeId
        ];
    }
    $connection->insertMultiple($table, $data);
}
```

In above code you can add your custom column value in **$data** array

```
$data[] = [
    $linkField => (int)$entity->getData($linkField),
    'store_id' => (int)$storeId,
    'ucri' => $entity->getData('ucri')
];
```

Also in order to show it in backend you need to override the collection responsible for it, otherwise value will be store in db but it will not be visible on backend form.

Comment: Thanks, I guess there is a bit more work I have to not overwrite core function but to extend  saveHandler using ExtensionPool? Like in this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146994/magento-2-extensionpool-read-handlers-and-save-handlers

Comment: Yes you can do it via saveHandler.